# Opening directories of PCs on a network using a string as a path

Tags: c#, networking, path, directory

My  windows application simply lets the user (department boss)  choose what PC's directory they want to navigate to that's on our network. Each computer name has a corresponding ID tag. For instance, if I wanted to open the accountant's C drive, I would select "Accountant's PC" in the combobox labeled selectPC. I then set the ID tag based on their choice  (for instance lets say its "ipx-12345") and display the ID tag in a text box (for visual verification). I want to invoke the path " \\ipx-12345\c$\ in my windows explorer. Note, the path will change based on what PC they chose in the combobox) How would I go about doing this using the ID tag in the textbox?

```
  //snippet of condition that sets the textbox's value to the ID tag of the PC chosen
  // in combo box named 'selectPC'

  if (selectPC.Text == ("Account's PC"))
            pcID.Text = "IPX-12345";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you populating this combobox?
if the data comes from a database (DataSet, BindingSource, etc ...) you can use the DataSource, DisplayMember and ValueMember of the combobox. If you are not using a database, and is relying on a list of data can implement something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> Data = new Dictionary<string,string>();
Data.Add("Acount1", @"\\ics#$1\");
Data.Add("Acount2", @"\\ics#$2\");
Data.Add("Acount3", @"\\ics#$3\");
Data.Add("Acount4", @"\\ics#$4\");

comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(Data, null);
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

So, to automatically select the item in the Combobox, you can get the result according to the ID in the combobox SelectedValue property.

```
combobox1.SelectedValue
```

Comment: The user chooses the PC they want in the dropdown portion in the combobox. Data for the box isnt coming from anywhere. In the if statement, the ID is set based on the string in the combobox that they selected. it is then displayed in a textbox. I was wondering how to extract that string in the textbox. When they press the OK button, the program will open windows explorer and go to \\ipx-12345\c$\

Comment: ok ... As you said, you included items such as ComboboxItens options in combobox via designer. I believe that would be a considerable improvement you apply this concept dictionary with him if you need to add a new form, just include the Dictionary. Besides more productive, your code would look more elegant. Simply include the creation of the combobox in your form load event and when the user clicks the OK button, you define "TextBox.Text = combobox1.SelectedValue. 'I hope I helped.